# HTML5 offline caching

Tags: html, offline-caching

I've read the following Mozilla Developer [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Offline_resources_in_Firefox) that explains how to implement HTML 5 offline resource caching in web apps.

I've tried testing this locally: added the mime type to the list, created the manifest file, changed my doctype to the HTML 5 doctype, specified the manifest attribute and the correct path on the HTML element--but still I don't see the manifest file being consumed by Firefox at all. I've also checked the access logs on Apache and didn't see any requests for the manifest file being made.

Has anyone given it a jab and had any success? I just don't know how to further troubleshoot the issue and would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: I have found http://manifest-validator.com/ to be useful to make sure that your manifest file is valid.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've compiled a few resources that may help you:

- [HTML 5 Offline Web Applications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html)
- [W3C's Offline Web Applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/)
- [Kaizou's Offline Web Applications Blog post (very helpful)](http://www.kaizou.org/2009/04/html-5-offline-web-applications/)

Comment: I haven't had the time to troubleshoot this issue further, but I also feel uneasy at leaving the question unanswered just because I'm not managing to get this running locally. I think it's best to leave it at accepting your answer for the quality resources provided.

Comment: I've also shared my experience taking a fairly complex web app offline in this post: http://blog.bitrzr.com/2010/10/html5-offline-webapps-practical-example.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes I have a full working prototype. At the time the manifest system in firefox was flawed. You can implement the maninfest system in a dynamic way using applicationCache.add(), applicationCache.remove() etc...

The manifest then just needs to be a json file. You will still need to have the @manifest in the html tag.